# sybase resulted in overflow

Tags: jdbc, sybase

I am using JDBC to get Informations from a Sybase Database. if I am trying to get large results from the Server I get an Error Message.(CS libary error: 33816852/1/0: cs converter: cslib user api layer: common libary error: The conversion/operation resulted in overflow.)

Maybe this is helpful

```
DataBaseHelper dbConnection = new DataBaseHelper();
Statement stmt = dbConnection.getConnection().createStatement();

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select *  From fak");

int i = 0;
while(rs.next()){
i++;
}
```

Comment: I've try to set the Fetchsize higher but it still doesn't work.

Comment: My guess is this error means that a data type conversion failed (eg trying from a `BIGINT` to `INT` because the `BIGINT` value is too big for an `INT`)

Comment: I had executed an Select Query only.

Comment: I tried some things and i got new Informations. My Programm works fine until I updated the Table in Sybase. I added about 10 Columns. Now i am getting this error.